# DataTable validation: ColumnChanging vs RowChanging

Tags: validation, ado.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

Here is my form code which saves dataset:

```
salesInvoiceBindingSource.EndEdit();
salesInvoiceLineBindingSource.EndEdit();
if (invoiceDataSet.HasChanges() && !invoiceDataSet.HasErrors)
{
    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.invoiceDataSet);
}
```

I've noticed that if I put validation code in ColumnChanging event:

```
void SalesInvoiceDataTable_ColumnChanging(object sender, 
                                   System.Data.DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.ColumnName == "CustomerCode")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)e.ProposedValue))
            e.Row.SetColumnError("CustomerCode", "Required");
        else
            e.Row.SetColumnError("CustomerCode", string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

then invoiceDataSet.HasErrors is false even when CustomerCode is empty string, because the event fires after dataset is saved. But if I put validation code in RowChanging event, it fires before UpdateAll() method; so it works fine. Why is it that? I'd like to use ColumnChanging event, not RowChanging event.

EDIT: This happens to new records, which were created by:

```
salesInvoiceBindingSource.AddNew();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Most operations that add or delete rows do not raise the ColumnChanged and ColumnChanging events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9a401%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)